# Can we use multiple scopes in Google People API in PHP

Tags: google-people-api

I am using google people API in php.
Please answer this question. 
i am very confused.
Basically i want to display email address, if anybody have solution suggest me

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('People API');
$client->setScopes(Google_Service_PeopleService::CONTACTS);
$client->setAuthConfig('credentials.json');
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setPrompt('select_account consent');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`setScopes`](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/blob/967ca9d565596f32cf12126e1394cfbc83d2ffed/src/Google/Client.php#L730:L735) supports an array of scopes.

```
$client->setScopes([
  Google_Service_PeopleService::CONTACTS,
  Google_Service_PeopleService::USER_EMAILS_READ
]);
```

Comment: Thanku @abraham for this solution.